# How to change the sort comparator or display Int? values on a Table with SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have the following table that mostly works when all the column values are strings:

```
struct Person : Identifiable {
  let id: String // assume names are unique for this example
  let name: String
  let rank: String
}

  @State var people = []
  @State var sort = [KeyPathComparitor(\Person.rank)]
  @State var selection: Person.ID? = nil

  private var rankingsCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

init (event: Event) {
  rankingsCancellable = event.rankingsSubject 
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { rankings in 
       var newRankings: [Person] = []
       for ranking in rankings {
         newRankings.append(Person(id: ranking.name, name: ranking.name, ranking: ranking.rank
       }
       newRankings.sort(by: sort)
       people = newRankings
    }
}

var body : some View {
  Table(people, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sort) {
    TableColumn("Name", value: \Person.name)
    TableColumn("Rank", value: \Person.rank)
  }
  .onChange(of: sortOrder) {
     people.sort(using: $0)
  }
}
```

This works well enough with one exception when the rank is unknown coming into the sink, its sent as an empty string and the empty strings sort before those with valid ranking.  Ideally, I'd like to have those without a ranking sort after until their rank is received.

I've tried a couple of things, changing `Person.rank` to an `Int` but the compiler gives the typical 'too complex' error when:

```
TableColumn("Rank", value: \Person.rank) { Text(\($0.rank)) } // rank is an int here
```

Alternatively I've tried to create a custom sort comparator when creating the `KeyPathComparator(\Person.rank)` but the documentation around that is limited and haven't been able to suss out a workable solution.

Any ideas how to get the Table to simply display Ints (which I imagine would have to be optionals in this instance) or add a string comparator that moves empty strings below populated strings?

TIA

Comment: What, exactly, is a rank? Is it a fixed ranking system?

Comment: Think of it as standings position in live event.  Rank 1 is the leader, 2 is in second place, etc.

Comment: I was going to suggest using an enum, but that won't work without a fixed number of ranks. Also, it seems to me that you are sorting it twice, once in the init, and once in the `Table`. Try sorting it in the init without sorting it in the `Table`. You have more control in your publisher.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing the table sort on the click of the column header.  I have to explicitly sort people with an onChange (which I omitted in the sample code, added now)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best answer I could find, tho admit it does seem a bit like a kludge.  Basically adding Int property for sorting and setting the sort to initially sort on this Person property

```
struct Person : Identifiable {
  let id: String // assume names are unique for this example
  let name: String
  let rank: String
  //Add rankForSort as an int which is a non displayed column
  let rankForSort: Int
}

  @State var people = []

  //Change to initial sort to non-displayed rank field
  @State var sort = [KeyPathComparitor(\Person.rankForSort)]
  
  @State var selection: Person.ID? = nil
  private var rankingsCancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil

init (event: Event) {
  rankingsCancellable = event.rankingsSubject 
    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
    .sink { rankings in 
       var newRankings: [Person] = []
       for ranking in rankings {
         // Ranking now coming through in the subject as Int?
         let rankString = ranking.rank != nil ? "\(ranking.rank!)" : ""
         newRankings.append(Person(id: ranking.name, name: ranking.name, ranking: rankString, rankForSort: ranking.rank ?? Int.max)
       }
       newRankings.sort(by: sort)
       people = newRankings
    }
}

var body : some View {
  Table(people, selection: $selection, sortOrder: $sort) {
    TableColumn("Name", value: \Person.name)
    TableColumn("Rank", value: \Person.rank)
  }
  .onChange(of: sortOrder) {
     people.sort(using: $0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do an initial sort and uses `didSet` which has the added benefit it doesn't use `onChange` which results in body called twice when resorting.

```
struct ProductsData {
    var sortedProducts: [Product]
    var sortOrder = [KeyPathComparator(\Product.name)] {
        didSet {
            sortedProducts.sort(using: sortOrder)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        sortedProducts = myProducts.sorted(using: sortOrder)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var data = ProductsData()
    
    var body: some View {
        ProductsTable(data: $data)
    }
}

struct ProductsTable: View {
    @Environment(\.horizontalSizeClass) private var horizontalSizeClass
    @Binding var data: ProductsData
    
    var body: some View {
        Table(data.sortedProducts, sortOrder: $data.sortOrder) {
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74450148/259521) to a different question for the full sample.